# Webpack only builds a bunch of empty Weakmaps and Weaksets out of a ES6 Class

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I have written a small javascript library.
Now the tests are written and I want to publish it.

But webpack just don't builds it the right way:

```
(() => {
    "use strict";
    require("regenerator-runtime/runtime"), require("lodash"), new WeakMap, new WeakMap, new WeakMap, new WeakMap, new WeakMap, new WeakMap, new WeakMap, new WeakMap, new WeakMap, new WeakMap, new WeakMap, new WeakSet, new WeakSet, new WeakSet, new WeakSet, new WeakSet, new WeakSet, new WeakSet, new WeakSet, new WeakSet, new WeakSet, new WeakSet, new WeakSet, new WeakSet, new WeakSet, new WeakSet, new WeakSet, new WeakSet
})();
```

That is what I get out of my [library code](https://github.com/MichaelBrauner/Whisk/blob/main/src/Whisk.js).

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');


module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    // plugins: [new webpack.ProgressPlugin()],
    // target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    entry: './src/Whisk.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'whisk.min.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: [
                    ['@babel/preset-env']
                ],
                plugins: [
                    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
                    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods"
                ]
            }
        }]
    },
}
```

When I test my code with jest, it works nice with this babel plugins.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't realise the exports of the entry point should be root nodes of the tree shaking process… and it strips away the class definition that is not used anywhere.

Comment: I really don't understand that. And now I switched to rollup.